# How do I press enter with pexpect

Tags: python, expect, pexpect

How do I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> with pexpect?  The problem is I dont know how to submit "enter"

```
-- Press ENTER to continue or Ctrl-C to abort. --

child.expect ('-- Press ENTER to continue or Ctrl-C to abort. --*')
child.sendline ('')
```

Comment: Is that `.sendline()` *not* sending a line? It certainly should.

Comment: You don't even need the `''` as argument to `sendline`. That's the default if you omit it.